# Fail azure data factory pipeline if notebook execution skipped

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

[image]I have build an ADF pipline and i am executing multiple databricks notebooks in the pipeline. When one of the notebook fails the remianing command in the notebook skipped but the pipeline did not fail. I want to make sure that the pipeline execution stops if the notebook fails and next command skipped

I have tried trigering an error so that the pipeline fails

NA

I want to make sure that the pipeline execution stops if the notebook fails and next command skipped

Answer (score 1):

If you connect the Azure Databricks acitivities as follows:

[image: Pipeline Design]

Notebook2-Activity will only be executed if the first Notebook-Activity is successfull.

Here the first activity fails and the next is not executed (Monitoring view of Azure Data Factory):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have setup the notebook in the same way. Before i added try catch, it was working fine but after try catch, if one of the command line fails remaining commands skipped but the notebook did not fail

Comment: Phps you could add a picture or json to your question to see how exactly your pipeline looks like? Thanks

Comment: I have added the picture of the pipeline. It should fail if any of the commands in previous notebook fails

Answer (score 0):

Use `assert`; here a the Scala code snippet:

```
try {
  ... ... ...
}
catch {
  case e: Exception => {
    println("exception caught while ... ... : " + e)
    assert(false)
  }
}
```

This will fail your Notebook Activity in Azure Data Factory.